# What is the space BUC$(\mathbf{R})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, notation

I am reading a PDE paper from the 80's and the author uses the space $\text{BUC}(\mathbf{R})$. My only guess has been "bounded uniformly continuous". Is this correct? Has anyone else run across this notation before?

Paper is: "Regularizing Effects for First-Order Hamilton-Jacobi Equations" by P.L. Lions. I unfortunately do not have a link to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the unpublished preprint "[Homogenization of Hamilton-Jacobi equations](http://localwww.math.unipd.it/%7Ebardi/didattica/Nonlinear_PDE_%20homogenization_Dott_%202011/LPV87.pdf)", Lions et al. define for a metric space $X$:
\begin{equation}
BUC(X) = \left\{ v \in C(X) \text{ s.t. $v$ is bounded and uniformly continuous on X}\right\}.
\end{equation}
Given your paper is by the same author and roughly the same topic, this should be the exact same definition in your case.